# How to access MacOS secure enclave from command line tool in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

We need a cli interface to the **secure enclave** on the Macbook Pro platform to implement a custom extension to openvpn to id the machine from which the vpn client is connecting. We did not find a cli tool to access the secure enclave, like *security* would do for the *keychain*. When we try to implement a MacOS command line tool ourselves in Xcode (based on the EllipticCurveKeyPair), trying to create a keypair in the command line tool results in the error that can be viewed here:

```
https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-34018
```

which says that the command line tool is missing the required entitlements to access the secure enclave. Now we face the problem of configuring the required entitlements for the command line target. It appears to be impossible to assign entitlements to a command line tool target

The error occurs when trying to generate a new key pair using

```
SecKeyGeneratePair(query as CFDictionary, &publicOptional, &privateOptional)
```

with publicOptional and private Optional being nil, and the query dictionary being

```
([String : Any]) $R7 = 4 key/value pairs {
[0] = {
key = "private"
value = 5 key/value pairs {
  [0] = {
    key = "perm"
    value = true
  }
  [1] = {
    key = "accc"
    value = 0x00000001020ebc10 {}
  }
  [2] = {
    key = "u_AuthCtx"
    value = 0x0000000102400020 {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
        isa = LAContext
      }
    }
  }
  [3] = {
    key = "labl"
    value = "no.agens.sign.private"
  }
  [4] = {
    key = "u_AuthUI"
    value = 0x00007fff9b492b28 {
      base__NSCFString@0 = {
        baseNSMutableString@0 = {
          baseNSString@0 = {
            baseNSObject@0 = {
              isa = __NSCFConstantString
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
[1] = {
key = "type"
value = "73"
}
```

In the console, we find error messages which are in alignment with what Xcode reports:

```
default 14:56:14.226372 +0100 secd  SecTool[29214]/1#1 LF=0 add Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-34018 "Client has neither com.apple.application-identifier, com.apple.security.application-groups nor keychain-access-groups entitlements" UserInfo={NSDescription=Client has neither com.apple.application-identifier, com.apple.security.application-groups nor keychain-access-groups entitlements}
```

Above errors happen when the command line tool is not run in the App Sandbox. In this thread, we saw a warning not to run command line tools in the App Sandbox: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/13/building-and-delivering-command-tools-for-catalina/#comment-41763.

Anyway, when we configure the command line tool target to run in the App Sandbox, we get this error:

```
0x7fff6ac3bb5e <+1981>: callq  0x7fff6ac3c3fe            ; symbol stub for: __snprintf_chk
0x7fff6ac3bb63 <+1986>: leaq   0x111e(%rip), %r8         ; "Sandbox creation failed: %s"
0x7fff6ac3bb6a <+1993>: movl   $0x800, %esi              ; imm = 0x800 
0x7fff6ac3bb6f <+1998>: movl   $0x0, %edx
0x7fff6ac3bb74 <+2003>: movl   $0x800, %ecx              ; imm = 0x800 
0x7fff6ac3bb79 <+2008>: xorl   %eax, %eax
0x7fff6ac3bb7b <+2010>: leaq   -0x880(%rbp), %rbx
0x7fff6ac3bb82 <+2017>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x7fff6ac3bb85 <+2020>: movq   %r13, %r9
0x7fff6ac3bb88 <+2023>: callq  0x7fff6ac3c3fe            ; symbol stub for: __snprintf_chk
0x7fff6ac3bb8d <+2028>: movq   %r14, 0x3668b68c(%rip)    ; gCRAnnotations + 16
0x7fff6ac3bb94 <+2035>: movq   %rbx, 0x3668b67d(%rip)    ; gCRAnnotations + 8
->  0x7fff6ac3bb9b <+2042>: ud2    =>Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
0x7fff6ac3bb9d <+2044>: xorl   %edi, %edi
0x7fff6ac3bb9f <+2046>: callq  0x7fff6ac3c446            ; symbol stub for: exit
```

which appears to be some error we could not identify at the time when the App Sandbox is initialized. Anyway, we still find a container folder at ~/Library/Containers/OurSecTool, which contains a Data folder, but no Container.plist file. In this context we could not find a related message in the console app.

We are signing the code with a Development certificate provided by Apple. When we manually sign the code to provide keychain-access-groups entitlements, the command line tool will fail on startup, logging the error "Killed:9".

What would be the correct approach to implement a command line tool in Xcode that can interface with the secure enclave? 
Or, as an alternative approach, are there any command line commands in MacOS that support creating keypairs, signing and encrypting based on the secure enclave?

Just in case that someone else needs to go down this path, here are some of the resources we reviewed during our research:

- Apple App Sandbox Overview and in detail https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html
- MacOS Code Signing in Depth https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html
- Listing of MacOS entitlements https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements
- Adding a capability to a target https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7
- Supported capabilities (macOS) https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devadf555df9
- Create, export and delete signing certificates https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09?sub=devd6ad10e16
- Code Signing Tasks https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html
- macOS code signing in depth https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html
- Inside Code Signing https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/
- iPhone Development 101 https://www.idev101.com/
- Storing keys in the secure enclave https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave?language=objc
- Series about code signing from a user’s point of view
- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/13/building-and-delivering-command-tools-for-catalina/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/01/15/code-signing-for-the-concerned-1-why/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/01/16/code-signing-for-the-concerned-2-creating-a-personal-certificate/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/01/31/code-signing-for-the-concerned-6-signing-scripts-and-command-tools/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/13/building-and-delivering-command-tools-for-catalina/
- MacOS App Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
- https://blog.fleetsmith.com/tcc-a-quick-primer/
- https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/hardened-runtime-sandboxing.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html
- https://opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55202/src/codesign.cpp.auto.html
- Darth Null and … Information Security, secure enclave https://darthnull.org/security/2018/05/31/secure-enclave-ecies/
- Darth Null and … Information Security, Mobile App Authentication using TouchID and Tidas https://darthnull.org/security/2016/02/10/tidas-auth/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/13/building-and-delivering-command-tools-for-catalina
- https://twocanoes.com/adding-a-command-line-tool-helper-to-a-mac-app-store-app/
- https://dev.to/ceri_anne_dev/how-to-make-a-command-line-tool-in-xcode-2f81

Comment: What specific API call is generating that error? Is it just returning the error code or is it logging a message to the console log? If logging a message, what is it? Have you checked the system console log (as opposed to, say, Xcode's console log display for just your app) to see if something is logged there during your attempt? You can use Console.app to view it. Are you code-signing your tool? Did you enable sandboxing or hardened runtime? What versions of macOS and Xcode are you using?

Comment: @KenThomases: we've added the required information, thanks for any idea.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: @paholg No, we resorted to writing a UI app and run it in headless mode.